# Smart Search Joomla One Result

Tags: joomla

I just enabled the Smart Search plug-in, and everything were great!

I just wanted to know when the query have ONE result, I'd love Joomla! will direct the user to this page directly.:(

Anyone has this issue and solved it ?

Comment: Do you mean if there is one result only you just want to go to that page, kind of like  I feel lucky in Google?

Comment: I wanted to know why I only ever get shown a single search result. I expect to see all related results. Have I misconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

In this file `components\com_finder\views\search\view.html.php` add the below line inside display function. After this line - `$this->assignRef('pagination', $pagination);`

```
if(count($results)==1){
    $app->redirect($results[0]->path);
}
```

This is a core file change so please do if necessary.

let me know if it does not work.