# joomla 3.3.0 smart search display of one result

Tags: php, joomla

I’m using Joomla 3.3.0 and want smart search to go directly to page when the query have ONE result. I know this question have been asked before in:
[Smart Search Joomla One Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025595/smart-search-joomla-one-result)

But the following solution doesn’t work for me.

"In this file      `components\com_finder\views\search\view.html.php` add the below line inside display function. After this line      `$this->assignRef('pagination', $pagination);`

```
if(count($results)==1){     $app->redirect($results[0]->path); } ” "
```

When I add the code, nothing changes.

I have a list of contacts, all assigned a number of area codes.

What I've done so far is:
- Enabled smart search
- added smart search module
- added area codes as tags in each contact
- Indexed content
- made a search filter only searching tags

I want the user to be able to search for the nearest contact by inserting their area code in the search box. When doing this I want the contact information to come right up on the page.

However, when searching the tag appears as a link, when clicking, then the contact name as a link, when clicking, then the contact information.

I want to skip the two first steps.

Comment: You may get a better answer than mine at the new [Joomla StackExchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) which just went into Beta.

Answer (score 0):

That question is answered for Joomla 2.5 so it won't work as described, secondly it's hacking the core which is both bad, having said that…

You're looking for the line:

```
    $this->pagination = &$pagination;
```

After that you want to place this:

```
    if(count($results) == 1)
    {
        $app->redirect($results[0]->path);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it :) however, it still won't work.

Comment: It should work, as I actually cut and pasted that out of my Joomla 3.3 dev site and tested it. I've just repasted it in and tested the search and it jumps straight to the first result.

Comment: That's strange, when I add the code, nothing changes. Is it because I search by tags?